# running a .py file on puTTY

Tags: putty

i am trying to execute a .py file on puTTY, which is also created on puTTY using nano editor.
upon executing file as "sudo python Filename.py"
an error pops up that sudo:python command not found
help!

Comment: PuTTY is a terminal emulator, it allows you to access remote systems, it doesn't run python files. Does the system that you are accessing have python installed?

Comment: Where are you running Putty? Does it have Python installed. What do you see if you run python -V on Putty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote server is Ubuntu use following command to install python:

sudo apt-get install python

On redhat/CentOs, Login with root user and run following command:

yum install python.